# OpenLayer3 remove control on the website

Tags: javascript, html, css, openlayers, openstreetmap

I put an OpenStreetMap on my website with openlayers.

How can I remove the default `OpenLayers` controls?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method: [ol.map.removeControl()](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#removeControl)